# Use of literals in antlr4 parsing grammar?

Tags: antlr4

I was looking at the Parser and Lexer grammar for Java which can be found in [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java). The Lexer grammar defines tokens such as semicolons and other things. Then, in the Parser grammar, the literal `';'` is used instead of writing `SEMI`. An example of where it is used [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/abce89734cea5e621f604b03786a77c5c2d67b1b/java/JavaParser.g4#L174). Why is that? Is there any reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a lexer rule is defined using a single string literal (and no other lexer rule is defined using the same literal), such as `SEMI: ';';`, the string literal can be used to refer to the rule instead of its name.

The reason this is allowed is that something like `statement ';'` is more readable than something like `statement SEMI`.